# Object destruction and processes

Tags: python, multithreading

So I have written a wrapper `WebApiSession` for a Web API. When an instance is created a login etc is done and a session is created. The session needs to be kept alive so the constructor launches a separate process handling this. The method `close()` logs out of the session as well as stops the process. Now ideally I would not want to have to call close(). Instead I want this to happen when the instance is not needed anymore, i.e. I would like to be able to remove the session.close() call below. Is this possible?

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

class WebApiSession:
    def __init__(self):
        # start session, login etc
        # ...
        # start touch loop
        self.touchLoop = Process(target = self.runTouchLoop)
        self.touchLoop.start()
    def runTouchLoop(self):
        self.touch()
        time.sleep(1)
        self.runTouchLoop()
    def touch(self):
        # touch session
        pass
    def close(self):
        # logout etc
        # ...
        self.touchLoop.terminate()
    def doSomething(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    session = WebApiSession()
    session.doSomething()
    session.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you could benefit from implementing `WebApiSession` [as a context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers). You can then treat your session like any other "context" that has special methods that must be called when it's opened and closed, like a file or other connection. It would also would give you the added bonus of neatly wrapping up errors and so on.

```
class WebApiSession(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass # other init stuff here, but don't connect yet.

    def __enter__(self): # entering the context.
        # start session, login, start touch loop
        self.touchLoop = Process(target = self.runTouchLoop)
        self.touchLoop.start()
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, traceback): # leaving the context.
        # Bonus feature: handle exception info here as needed!
        self.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with WebApiSession() as session:
        session.doSomething()
```